# Embed Custom URL Protocol in MS Teams Chat

Tags: url, microsoft-teams, url-scheme, custom-url-protocol

We use Microsoft Teams desktop for daily communications.  We have other tools which create custom URL protocol links which greatly aids communication via email, etc.  The issue is Teams does not seem to recognize those URLs.  It'll underline them (presumably from the underlying copied formats), but nothing happens when you click.  Non custom URLs such as onenote:// work.  Has anyone gotten custom URLs to work in Teams?

Comment: I'm able to repro this issue from my end, taking this for internal discussion.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT any further comments?

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT any further comments?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to use new custom handlers in MSTeams Desktop App, that are not already build in. I raised a change request at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/b4dae423-6e06-ed11-a81b-6045bd7d68ae that you and all interested might want to support.

Comment: Did anything become of this change request?  I was shocked when I downloaded "New Teams" the other day and this wasn't fixed!

Comment: Same here, Microsoft seems to ignore that problem on any channel I tried.